# Lets consider a cube with side $2$, which is cooling in an environment. Find its temperature at any point at any time: $u(x,y,z,t)$

Tags: thermodynamics, differential-equations, cooling

> Lets consider a cube with side $2$, which has an initial temperature of $1$°K and it is cooling in an environment of temperature $0$°K. Find its temperature at any point at any time: $u(x,y,z,t)$.

That is what I'm doing:

Its temperature at any moment in any point is given by the PDE:
$$\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial t}=\alpha\left(\dfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}+\dfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2}+\dfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial z^2}\right)$$
subjected to:

I.C.: $u(x,y,z,0)=1$.

F.C.1: $-k\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}=h\cdot u$, for $x=1,-1$.

F.C.2: $-k\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}=h\cdot u$, for $y=1,-1$.

F.C.3: $-k\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial z}=h\cdot u$, for $z=1,-1$.

To solve this I do the change of variable $\tau=\alpha t$, so, by the chain rule, $\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial t}=\alpha\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial \tau}$, and suppose that $u=\alpha(x)\beta(y)\gamma(z)G(\tau)$, so the PDE becomes:
$$\dfrac{1}{G}\dfrac{d G}{d \tau}=\dfrac{1}{\alpha}\dfrac{d^2 \alpha}{d x^2}+\dfrac{1}{\beta}\dfrac{d^2 \beta}{d y^2}+\dfrac{1}{\gamma}\dfrac{d^2\gamma}{d z^2}$$
subjected to:

I.C.: $u(x,y,z,0)=1$.

F.C.1: $\dfrac{d \alpha}{d x}+\dfrac{h}{k}\alpha=0$, for $x=1,-1$.

F.C.2: $\dfrac{d \beta}{d y}+\dfrac{h}{k}\beta=0$, for $y=1,-1$.

F.C.3: $\dfrac{d \gamma}{d z}+\dfrac{h}{k}\gamma=0$, for $z=1,-1$.

By the Newton's cooling law:

$$\dfrac{1}{G}\dfrac{d G}{d \tau}=-\lambda^2,\ \lambda >0.$$

so
$$G=ce^{-\lambda^2\tau}.$$

And so, in the other hand,
$$\dfrac{1}{\alpha}\dfrac{d^2 \alpha}{d x^2}+\dfrac{1}{\beta}\dfrac{d^2 \beta}{d y^2}+\dfrac{1}{\gamma}\dfrac{d^2\gamma}{d z^2}=-\lambda^2$$

And I don't know how to solve this equation, and I think I'm missing some frontier conditions. Thanks.

Comment: The terms $\alpha''/\alpha$, $\beta''/\beta$, $\gamma''/\gamma$ are functions only of $x$, $y$ and $z$ respectively. What does that tell you?

Comment: For some function, the other functions are constants